# QProgresdialog: busy waiting bar is not moving while function is executing

Tags: c++, qt, thread-safety, progress-bar

I'm trying to show a busy waiting bar when one function is executing, my problem is it stop moving once the function starts.

```
MyProgressDialog *progBar= new MyProgressDialog();
    QProgressBar* bar = new QProgressBar(progBar);
    bar->setRange(0, 0);
    bar->setValue(0);

    progBar->setBar(bar);
    QString labeltext=QString("<qt> <center><big><b>%1</b></big></center> <br><b>%2</b><br> %3 <br><b>%4</b><br> %5</qt>")
                         .arg(progBar->labeltext)
                         .arg("File in :")
                         .arg(FileI)
                         .arg("File out :")
                         .arg(FileO);
    progBar->label->setText(labeltext);    
    progBar->setValue(10);
    progBar->show();
    progBar->setValue(20);
    Sleep(500);
    progBar->setValue(50);
    Sleep(500);
    MyFunction(FileI,FileO,mode,key);
    Sleep(500);
    progBar->setValue(80);
    Sleep(500);
    progBar->setValue(100);
    progBar->close();
    delete bar;
    delete progBar;
```

I warpped my function with a sleep and set value in purpose to let it moving but in vain, when I remove them MyProgressdialog didn't show its contents, am I need to lunch my function in a separate thread ?
 I tried to use QFutureWatcher:

```
 QFutureWatcher<void> futureWatcher;
                       QFuture<void> f1 = run(
                                              MyFunction,
                                              filePath,
                                              file.absolutePath()+"/OUT_"+fileN,
                                              1,
                                              key
                                              );
                       QObject::connect(&futureWatcher, SIGNAL(finished()), progBar, SLOT(reset()));
                       QObject::connect(progBar, SIGNAL(canceled()), &futureWatcher, SLOT(cancel()));
                       QObject::connect(&futureWatcher, SIGNAL(progressRangeChanged(int,int)), progBar, SLOT(setRange(int,int)));
                       QObject::connect(&futureWatcher, SIGNAL(progressValueChanged(int)), progBar, SLOT(setValue(int)));

                       // Start the computation.
                       futureWatcher.setFuture(f1);
                       // Display the dialog and start the event loop.
                       progBar->exec();
                       futureWatcher.waitForFinished();
                       delete progBar;
```

It works fine and my bar is moving when I call MyFunction just one time (for one file) but the problem occurs when I call MyFunction more than one time (for many files successively): it works but I get the same OUT_file for all files treated, I think it is multithreading issue.

**EDIT:**  `class MyProgressDialog`

```
class MyProgressDialog: public QProgressDialog
{
  Q_OBJECT

  public:

    MyProgressDialog()
      {

      qDebug()<<"MyProgressDialog constructor";

      label=new QLabel(this);

      QPalette* palette = new QPalette();
      palette->setColor(QPalette::Window,"#F8F8FF");
      setPalette(*palette);

      QFont* font = new QFont("Courier New");
          font->setItalic(true);
          font->setPixelSize(15);
      setFont(*font);
      adjustSize();

     setWindowIcon(QIcon(QApplication::applicationDirPath()+"/icons/icon1.png"));
     setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
     setMinimumWidth(500);
     setMinimumHeight(200);
     labeltext=QString("Please wait until Encryption/Decryption was done");
     label->setText(labeltext);
     label->adjustSize();
     label->setWordWrap (true);
     setLabel(label);

     setRange(0,100);
     setWindowTitle("MyFunction progress");        
     setModal(true);    

    }
    ~MyProgressDialog()
    {
        qDebug()<<"MyProgressDialog destructor";
        delete label;
    }



public:

  int value;     
  QString labeltext;
  QLabel* label;

};
```

Comment: Could you provide us what is fileN, also MyFunction implementation would be usefull. Is it method of a class or standalone function?

Comment: FileI and FileO are qstring (absolue path of files) , MyFunction is a standalone function written in c language.

Comment: I'm talking about `file.absolutePath()+"/OUT_"+fileN` in this context

Comment: it is the base name of my file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI in Qt is event driven. So executing your code in same thread as ui will block every ui event untill your function is finished. There are two aproaches to show progress.

1. Use thread for computing and send update events to UI
2. Easier way: after each `setValue` and `show` calls call `QApplication::processEvents();` static method. Calling `QApplication::processEvents()` will dispatch events currently queued on event loop. Those events include all ui related events

Here is code sample for gcc/mingw gcc

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QProgressBar>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QProgressBar bar;
    bar.setRange(0, 100);
    bar.show();
    app.processEvents();
    usleep(250000);

    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
    {
            bar.setValue(i * 10);
            app.processEvents();
            usleep(250000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It shows progress bar and steps it by 10 every 0,25s

Your code should look something like this:

```
MyProgressDialog *progBar= new MyProgressDialog();
QProgressBar* bar = new QProgressBar(progBar);
bar->setRange(0, 100); // note your "busy state won't be shown as you're changing value right after show
bar->setValue(0);

progBar->setBar(bar);
QString labeltext=QString("<qt> <center><big><b>%1</b></big></center> <br><b>%2</b><br> %3 <br><b>%4</b><br> %5</qt>")
                     .arg(progBar->labeltext)
                     .arg("File in :")
                     .arg(FileI)
                     .arg("File out :")
                     .arg(FileO);
progBar->label->setText(labeltext);    
progBar->setValue(10);
progBar->show();
QApplication::processEvents(); // HERE
progBar->setValue(20);
QApplication::processEvents(); // HERE
Sleep(500);
progBar->setValue(50);
QApplication::processEvents(); // HERE
Sleep(500);
MyFunction(FileI,FileO,mode,key);
Sleep(500);
progBar->setValue(80);
QApplication::processEvents(); // HERE
Sleep(500);
progBar->setValue(100);
progBar->close();
QApplication::processEvents(); // HERE
delete bar;
delete progBar;
```

Comment: thank you @Kamil, same result with `QApplication::processEvents()`, I will try the first approach and see.

Comment: If you have same result with QApplication::processEvents then you're doing something wrong. Where did you put "processEvents" calls?

Comment: I set the rang 0,0 to let it in a busy state, I called `QApplication::processEvents();` before calling MyFunction, is that sufficient or should I call `myapp.processEvents();` so how get the current instance of QApplication !!!

Comment: You don't need instance of QApplication. processEvents is static method. You must change range to make progress bar show proper value. Also as I said before you must call processEvents after EACH call of setValue

Comment: @oumaya Show us `MyProgressDialog` implementation. Maybe you're hiding some errors there

Comment: yeah exactly the same code,but my problem is not about the value of progress bar even if I set range 0,0 I have same result, so my problem is the event of moving (busy or value set) it stops when Myfunction is called!!!! so what do you suggest? thank you for your time and your patience  @Kamil :)

Comment: :D Problem solved, I added `QApplication::processEvents();` within MyFunction (in a while loop that treat my file) so it works , thank you Kamil am so grateful for your ideas and time :).

Comment: If you want to keep animations of progress bar while doing processing you must move your processing to another thread, so your ui event processing (repaints mostly) won't get blocked by your processing method. I'll take a look at your current code and try to find whats wrong and post new answer

Comment: QApplication::processEvents() doesn't work for me, weird. since. MFC works perfect when blocked and update message pump manually.

Comment: it works. sorry for the confusion. my other bugs prevent progress updating.